# Homework Clarification: Character Strings

Tags: java, terminology

We have to implement a map, instruction reads: "**The key for each entry is unique. The key for each entry is a character string.**"

So is the key a `char` or `String` or an array of `char`?

Comment: It's a String...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A character string is a series of characters represented by bits of code and organized into a single variable. This string variable holding characters can be set to a specific length or analyzed by a program to identify its length.

I think this quote can clarify your question, it should be a `String`

Answer (score 1):

It should be a string. It is impossible to be a 'char' since 'char' cannot represent any string. In case of array of 'char', it should be clearly stated.